# Is an arrangement of solenoid valves the only way to achieve fluid redirection?

Tags: water, solenoid-valve, flow-control

Not sure if this fits in the charter of this site. If not, pointer to another stack-exchange site would be great.

For a rain-water harvesting system that I am designing for my house, I need to be able to control the flow of water out from/into a reservoir in 3-4 different directions, i.e. a case of multiple inputs and outputs.

I am only aware of solenoid valves as the mechanism, that I could control via a microcontroller, to achieve the desired flow-path -- including having a water-pump on/off. Are there other mechanisms to achieve such goals (of course, under microcontroller supervision) ?

Comment: Not an electrical engineering question.  Should be closed.

Comment: @mikeY, not sure what your definition of EE question is, but are you aware of a better forum ? Solenoid valves and it's alternatives are not EE ?? Really !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are motor-operated valves too.

There are all kinds of ways to manage fluid flow, like pumping, controlling valves, changing height, and changing pressure somehow.  In your case however, either controlling pumps (if gravity feed is not enough) or controlling valves somehow sounds like the easiest way.

Comment: Do not have enough reputation to up-vote, yet - but that certainly is a good answer. Will research those methods -- just to quench the knowledge thirst, but will probably go with the valves, as you say.